# Temporarily Disable Responsiveness Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in the middle of developing a page using Twitter Bootstrap. At the current stage of development, changing to a different device resolution other than desktop breaks the layout of the site horribly. How can I disable the responsiveness aspect of bootstrap until I'm ready to develop for it? I'd like to have a desktop version of this site published and I can't if it breaks on different resolutions. I don't have a bootstrap-responsive.css file, it's all baked in to bootstrap.css.

Comment: Is it the standard framework or have you modified the CSS file ?

Comment: @Sherbrow heavily modified CSS

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove Bootstrap Responsive CSS

In your source code, find the style declarations:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just remove the second CSS. Have only this:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

#### If all the files are combined...

You need to find and remove the `@media` queries, responsible for screen widths. Remove all the `@media` queries, which have:

```
@media screen and
(min-width: X px) and
(max-width: X px)

@media screen and
(min-device-width: X px) and
(max-device-width: X px)
```

Comment: From question: **I don't have a bootstrap-responsive.css file, it's all baked in to bootstrap.css.**

Comment: @Peter I didn't notice. Updated the answer.

Comment: it's more of a problem if you are using the CDN version and can't change nothing.