# Preventing navbar from resizing on Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, resize, navbar

I've been stuck for like 2h trying to prevent my navbar from resizing, as I built a webapp which I don't want to be responsive designed.

The navbar started stacking components and shrinking whenever the browser window was resized, so I tried different solutions I found with some googling and also here in stackoverflow. None of them worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415865/3736964

[Temporarily Disable Responsiveness Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151832/temporarily-disable-responsiveness-bootstrap)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151865/3736964

I even went to http://getbootstrap.com/customize and created my own bootstrap version by unchecking the "responsive utilities" and changing two LESS variables:

```
@grid-float-breakpoint = 0   
@grid-float-breakpoint-max =  0
```

(I also tried `99999` and stuff for that breakpoint max value)
I downloaded it and tested with no luck.

I still wasn't able to prevent the navbar from resizing whenever the window was resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't the way it should be done, for sure, but I couldn't figure out a cleaner and non-intrusive way of preventing the navbar from shrink.

I just added an inline style (you can do it also by overriding it on your .css files) for my `nav` element:

```
<nav class="class="navbar navbar-default" style="min-width: 1300px !important;">
  ...
</nav>
```

The `!important` aims for that style rule not being overriden. I've set the `min-width` according to my needs, so if anyone finds this useful, should change it for his particular needs.

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav class="class="navbar navbar-default" style="min-width: 1300px!important;"></nav>
```

If you want to fix is and if you want to fix is at the top

use css 
`body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}`
and class navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  plus also if you want to fix it use `min-width: 1300px !important;` in the style tag

Thanks With Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't really understand how this can improve my current solution

Comment: use min-width: 1300px !important;  if still not works please use jsfiddle  to show your code i will try to help you

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here, I've already done that as detailed in my solution :)